# How to check watermark applied or not?

Tags: php, image, watermark

I am trying to apply watermark on my all image with in folder.For get working this i am using this line of code.

```
<?php

  function endsWith($currentString, $target)
  {
    $length = strlen($target);
     if ($length == 0) {
      return true;
    }

  return (substr($currentString, -$length) === $target);
 }
  if ($handle = opendir('images')) {
 while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

        if (endsWith($entry,'.jpg')==0){
          echo   "<br/> $entry: is ignored.\n  ";
          continue;
        }
         echo "<br/> $entry\n  ";
   $image_path = "images/".$entry; 
   $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('wa/ap.png');   
  $watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
  $watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);  
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
  if ($image === false) {
     return false;
    }
   $tragetedImageSize = getImageSize($image_path);
  $wmPositionX = $tragetedImageSize[0]- $watermark_width - 6;
  $wmPositionY = $tragetedImageSize[1] - $watermark_height - 6;
   imagealphablending($image, true);
   imagealphablending($watermark, true);
   imagecopy($image, $watermark, $wmPositionX, $wmPositionY, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);
   imagejpeg($image, "images/$entry");
   imagedestroy($image);
   imagedestroy($watermark);

     }
    }
    closedir($handle);
   }
 ?>
```

this code working fine. But now If add a new image in this folder and again run my php code then other image which alredy watermarked last time. I want skip those image which is watermarked last time .

Extra :: One more this if images folder have more sub folder then what code need tobe changed ?

Thanks

Comment: One way would be to add something to the name of all the .jpg files that are already modified (watermark added) so next time you know if it's modified..but that depends on the interactions of your files. Or you could create another folder and move them after you apply watermark.

Comment: Thanks for you idea this is already in my mind . This is my last option.